# What's the difference between ELM and NNAR?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I'm working with time series forecasting using the two techniques that involve neural networks, the Extreme Learning Machine and the Autoregressive Neural Network. Reading the two methodologies, the first proposal by Huang et al. (2006) and the second explained in Dietz (2010) and Zhang (2003), cannot understand the main differences between the algorithms. Could more experienced people cite such differences?